# Return a complex object from page.evaluate using puppeteer?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I was asked to create a task that clicks random links on a website ( in order to test something).

So I have something like this :

```
 await page.evaluate((a, shuf) =>
                                {
                                  function shuffle(array)
                                   {
                                     //...
                                     return array;
                                   }

    //let's get the first one
    let anchor = shuffle([...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter(...)[0];

    (anchor).click();

 });
```

1)  Notice that I had to inline the `shuffle` function , because otherwise , it doesn't know it. Is there any way to put this function outside `page.evaluate`  , and "send" it to the evaluate function ?

2) I don't want to click the anchor (`(anchor).click();`) it in the evaluate function. I want to return the DOM object of `anchor` and to do some other manipulations *then* click it. The problem is that a DOM  is a complex object which is not serialized , so I can't return it. Is there any way to do a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to add shuffle() to the browser context:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.shuffle = array => {
    return array.reverse()
  }
})
```

Now you can use it in evaluate:

```
let shuffled = await page.evaluate((array) => window.shuffle(array), [1,2,3,4,5])
```

2) Maybe something like this?

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.anchors = [...document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')]
  return 'something else'
})

await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.anchors[0].click()
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that after leaving the `page` object  , all the props will be available later on that page.